# Material UI (React): how to style the Input wrapping the Select?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following JSX:

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>My label</InputLabel>
  <Select>
    ...
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

I use the `classes` prop to style various aspects of the `FormControl` and `Select`. The trouble is that the `Select` component implicitly wraps itself with an `Input` component, and thus in reality looks something like this:

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>My label</InputLabel>
  <Input>
    <Select>
      ...
    </Select>
  </Input>
</FormControl>
```

That's where I'm having problems: how can I style the `Input` that is wrapping the `Select`? I've looked at the CSS APIs for both `Select` and `FormControl`, and neither of them allow you to style that `Input`.

I know I can add a className to the `FormControl` and then style it using an external stylesheet, but I want to style it on the component level.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

A snippet of my code (with dummy content), for illustration (was requested):

```
<FormControl
  classes={myClasses.formControl}
  >
  <InputLabel
    htmlFor='country'
    classes={myClasses.inputLabel}
  >
    Select country
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={countryCode}
    onChange={onInputChange}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'countryCode',
      id: 'country',
    }}
    classes={myClasses.select}
  >
    <MenuItem value='US'>United States</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='GB'>United Kingdom</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='FR'>France</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution.

To style the wrapping `Input` component, you need to explicitly define it in the `Select`'s `input` prop, and then pass the `classes` prop to that `Input`.

Here is an example:

```
<Select
  input={
    <Input
      classes={myClasses.input}
    />
  }
>
  ...
</Select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via standard css import (look at generate code and retrieve the css path) or you can style it using a wrapper and styling it with styled-components. A snippet with a real case would be useful for me to be more specific.

Comment: I don't think you can actually do it this way with material ui. The reason being is it auto generates the class names, so they are not deterministic. You can override this behaviour, but its not recommended. Sadly React material-ui is missing a fair amount of configurable CSS endpoints as well :(.

Comment: Thank you Mosé, I know I can do it with CSS import, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. I added a snippet - hope it helps. Regarding styled-components. Would you be able to provide an example?